# How to manage user roles with AWS IAM Identity center?

Tags: amazon-iam

I can't understand the logic behind AWS IAM Identity center.
I am trying to move from IAM to IAM Identity center to federate access to multiple accounts. "Standard" IAM allows defining on a per-user level, I can't figure out how to do it in IAM identity center.

With Identity center, I assign permission sets **to accounts** and then assign users/groups to accounts as well...

***How can I define which permissions sets each user has if permission sets are assigned on account, not the user level?***

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The console says that I can assigned permissions to a group
[image]

But when I start assigning permissions sets, they are assigned to ACCOUNTS only. So there is no way to say user X can only be PowerUser but not Administrator when accessing the account Y
[image]

Comment: ' Previously in IAM I could define permissions on per-user level.' - are you aware that IAM identity center was previously for SSO and not just 'regular IAM'? It's just been renamed. Do you have a single sign on solution?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary poor wording on my end. Yes, I am aware that it is a different service. I am trying to start using it to simplify access to multiple accounts. I'd like to be able to say "employee X can assume only PowerUser role when accessing these accounts in my organization".

With "regular IAM" I need to manually create per account credentials and assign a policy, I was hoping that  IAM Identity center would allow to do it for me across all accounts in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

IAM Identity Center -> AWS Accounts -> Select your account -> Assigned users and groups -> Select your Group name -> Change permission sets button.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the wording, when assigning policies and groups, AWS seems to do exactly what is expected – sets access per group and account.

It can be verified on the account page
[image]

My issue was that I separately added a user to all accounts outside of any groups, so changes to group access were not reflected on a user level. :(